# Dealing with "Null" JSON parameters in Flask (+MySQL)

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that connects to a MySQL database. I am using `httr2` in `R` to send POST requests to this endpoint in a localhost environment. I am running into an issue, though. When a variable is not specified inside an R function  with `httr2`, it passes through "null" in the JSON request:

Like so: `{"year":2016,"team":null}`

I thought about creating an auxiliary function to take a dictionary from `request.json` and remove the `null` values, which I assume (??) are treated as `None` in Python, and then spit-out a new dictionary with which to use inside the endpoint.

```
def remove_none(d):
    for k, v in list(d.items()):
        if v is None or v == 'Null' or v == 'null':
            del d[k]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            remove_none(v)
    return d
```

When using a testing endpoint, this function *DOES* remove any keys having `None` (`null`) and returns the correct dictionary. But when putting it into action in the endpoint at hand, it evidently fails and no `WHERE` filter is applied. (`db_read` is a utility function that extends `cursor`, if that matters.)

**When supplying both parameters, the endpoint properly returns the `WHERE`-filtered data. So this seems to be an issue when any `null` values are passed through by the POST.**

```
def get_data(val_a = None, val_b = None):
    parameter_content = request.json
    parameter_content = remove_none(parameter_content)

    # reassign var. names from POST-ed data
    if parameter_content is not None:
        if "val_a" in parameter_content:
           val_a= parameter_content["val_a"]
        if "val_b" in parameter_content:
            val_b= parameter_content["val_b"]

    # build statements and read
    if val_a is not None and val_b is None:
        data = db_read("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE val_a = %s""", (val_a,))
    if val_b is not None and val_a is None:
        data = db_read("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE val_b = %s""", (val_b,))
    if val_a is not None and val_b is not None:
        data = db_read("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE val_a = %s AND val_b = %s""", (val_a,val_b,))
    else:
        data = db_read("""SELECT * FROM table""")

    # return data
    return jsonify(data)
```

I would also appreciate any tips on how to structure my SQL statements to prevent injection and any thoughts as to trimming down my code. There has to be a way to build the proper statements without resorting to `if/else` chains. This just looks clunky.